# How to learn SAP ERP (without buying it)?

Tags: abap

I would like to learn SAP ERP. Is there a SAP ERP student edition?

How do people practice SAP ERP? By trial version?

If there is no way to download a free/trial, is learning Ofbiz useful to work in the future with SAP?

Comment: There is alot of documentation about SAP around. I have been working with sap for my final assessment and found ALOT docs by searching google. GL!

Comment: @Developer Art: Why not a student edition! Many companies offer a limited edition to students!

Comment: Because the software would obviously be useless in the hands of one individual.

Comment: I know ... I didn't think it was like Age Of Empire where you can fight the others or play in the multiplayer mode ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can get a trial version [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/nw-downloads). the installation should not be too hard and there are many books which will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much ... with this version, I can at least practise ABAP.

Answer (score 2):

Some universities offer degrees during which you learn SAP. 
Some companies are willing to hire you even if you don't know SAP and train you.
I came across both situations. Probably there are some courses as well.

EDIT: But I agree with the TFD: unless you are very into money(SAP jobs are very well paid) look for sth different.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be try for some remote access SAP IDES. IDES is the educational/student version. Many 3rd party vendors offer remote system access to SAP servers hosted on their racks + BASIS services. Choose your product/module, like NetWeaver BI or R/3 for learning ABAP etc & purchase the evaluation version. Evaluation SAP software is the exact form the one SAP AG uses in their training centers. Its better to have a first hand look & explore opportunities, as SAP is just vast! All the best.